# How to adjust my code so it replicates this image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}


\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Dijkstra]
    \SetGraphUnit{4}
    \Vertices{square}{G,D,A,F}
    \WE(F){H}
    \EA(A){B}
    \EA(D){C}
    \NO(A){E}
    \draw [->] (H) -- (F);
    \Edge[label=$1$](H)(F)
    \Edge[label=$4$](G)(F)
    \Edge[label=$2$](H)(G)
    \Edge[label=$2$](G)(D)
    \Edge[label=$3$](D)(C)
    \draw [->] (F) -- (E);
    \Edge[label=$4$](F)(E)
    \Edge[label=$3$](A)(D)
    \Edge[label=$2$](A)(E)
    \Edge[label=$1$](A)(B)
    \Edge[label=$2$](A)(C)
    \Edge[label=$2$](C)(B)
    \draw [->] (E) -- (B);
    \Edge[label=$3$](E)(B)




    \SetUpEdge[lw=4pt,color=gray]
    \Edges[style={opacity=.3}](H,F,E,B)





\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the above stuff I am trying to get the code to look like the purple image, however I want to sustain the same colour coding from my code of gray for the arrows and just black for everything else, please can you help me adjust my code as everything I adjust makes it look worse as shown in the code already with my arrow attempt for example. UPDATE: I got the arrow concept working, now I am just trying to make the arrow head bigger and make the circles and such look like the diagram in my image. UPDATE #2: Made arrows bigger

I don't know if I a clarified it before, but I am having trouble adjusting the nodes to look like the image, everytime I try this the nodes become jumbled and look nothing like the image.

Comment: Can you provide a more descriptive interpretation of "...this image" in your title? To be specific, change your title to be more descriptive of the actual problem/scope.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It just needs to look like the image, except the purple colour becomes black.

Comment: "this image" perhaps has some meaning to you, but not to the general public who use this site.

Comment: If you want the circles in your image to be filled purple without an outline and with white text inside of the, `\SetVertexNormal[FillColor = violet, TextColor=white, LineColor=violet]` might be useful.

Comment: The image has no meaning to me, its just  a visual representation of what I am trying to aim for now. Additionally I am not trying to set the fill colours, its fine as it is in my initial code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my installation `tkz-graph` does not exist, but it was part of my TeXLive2019 installation. Anyway, I was trying to understand the `graphs` library a bit better, and even with my current low level of understanding this graph is very easy to obtain, yet presumably with a better understanding it would become even easier and more streamlined.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,graphs,quotes}
\tikzset{growing arrow/.style={decorate,
decoration={show path construction, 
moveto code={},
lineto code={
\draw[line width=1pt,-{Stealth[width=12pt,length=12pt]}]  
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --  (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
\fill ($ (\tikzinputsegmentlast)!6pt!0:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $) coordinate (aux)
 ($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!0.5pt!90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $) 
 -- ($ (aux)!2pt!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $) 
 --($ (aux)!2pt!90:(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) $) 
 -- ($ (\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!0.5pt!-90:(\tikzinputsegmentlast) $) ;
},
curveto code={},
closepath code={},
}}}
%\definecolor{prp}{RGB}{99,51,156}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=pi*0.5cm,font=\sffamily]
\graph[nodes={circle,fill,text=white,minimum size=2em}] 
{{
a[yshift=-1cm] -- {
 b[xshift=2mm]   --[growing arrow,"5"] d[yshift=3mm] ,
c [> "2"] -- e [> "10",xshift=3mm]} -- f
};
 c -- b [> "1"];
 c --["8"] d ;
 e --["2"] d;
 e --["5"] f;
 d --["6"] f;
};
\draw[growing arrow] (a) to["4"] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has not been done using Dijkstra (my sample code was simple so keeping it in line with that is helpful), additional to which I didn't need the nodes filling black. Good attempt though and thanks.

Comment: @SomeT Well, as I wrote, your code does not even compile on my installation, so how would I know what vertex style you are using? Your question reads "How to adjust my code so it replicates this image?" and from the comments I take that you do not want purple. Well, others already commented on that.

Comment: Ah ok I meant more I am trying to adjust my code than change it completely

Comment: @SomeT As I said, the package you are using is no longer part of TeXLive. So I really cannot use your code, and you may not be able to use it either once you update your installation.

Comment: What does that even mean, growing arrows and selling code?

Comment: Also I am using Overleaf

Comment: @SomeT At a given point `overleaf` will update their TeX installation, too. They are far behind and using outdated packages, which is one of the many reasons why I will never use it.